# bUnit: Simple markup verification for <path> tag

Tags: bunit

Here is the SVG code:

```
<svg>
    <path />
</svg>
```

Here is the bUnit test that fails for some reason:

```
public void Chart_Render_MarkupContainsPath()
{
    var chart = RenderComponent<Chart>();

    var path = chart.Find( "path" );

    path.MarkupMatches( "<path />" );
}
```

Error message:

```
Message: 
    Bunit.HtmlEqualException : HTML comparison failed. 
    
    The following errors were found:
      1: The element at path(0) is missing.
      2: The element at path(0) was not expected.
    
    Actual HTML: 
    <path></path>
    
    Expected HTML: 
    <path></path>
```

What is the reason of failing?

Thanks

Comment: Turns out that's actually a bug, which I will attempt to fix in the AngleSharp.Diffing library, which is used to compare markup semantically.

https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Diffing/pull/27

Comment: @EgilHansen thank you for quick reaction! Yeah, we thought that it might be a bug.

Comment: I'll be pushing an update to bUnit later today that should solve the problem.

Comment: @EgilHansen hey, good news! Could you please also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75345362/bunit-check-for-attribute-addition ?

Comment: Here you go: https://www.nuget.org/packages/bunit

Comment: @EgilHansen great! Thanks a lot. Seems like there might be one more little bug